# Removing NA in data table for one way ANOVA

Tags: r, na, anova, oneway

I'm currently working on a project for school where I need to run a one way ANOVA on the %uninsured motorists from each state divided by region. I'm trying to remove the NA from the table, but am having trouble.

```
 > motor
 MW   NE   SE    W
 1  0.11 0.09 0.25 0.16
 2  0.13 0.11 0.20 0.16
 3  0.12 0.04 0.13 0.22
 4  0.10 0.07 0.10 0.32
 5  0.09 0.09 0.08 0.10
 6  0.13 0.15 0.16 0.08
 7  0.12 0.07 0.25 0.09
 8  0.13 0.09 0.06 0.15
 9  0.07 0.11 0.28 0.30
 10 0.07 0.09 0.18 0.12
 11 0.13   NA 0.12 0.09
 12 0.17   NA 0.21 0.15
 13 0.06   NA   NA 0.07
 14 0.18   NA   NA   NA
 15 0.08   NA   NA   NA
 16 0.11   NA   NA   NA

 > aov(motor)
 Error in terms.default(formula, "Error") : 
   no terms component nor attribute
```

I've tried using na.omit, complete.cases, and na.rm, but either parts of my data were removed or I received the same error message. I have also tried

```
summary(lm(motor))
```

This gave me a P-value of .77, which is different from the P-value I received when running the data in excel (P = 0.007859928)

I know I'm just missing something small, but have tried looking for the last two hours to find it with no avail.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hye,
your formula is not good , you need to have a column as factor (motorist for exemple) and to plot. This column is missing in your data. Supose you include this column "motorist"

```
motorist<-c("A","B","C","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","C","C","A","B","C")
motor<-cbind(motorist,motor)
aov(w~motorist,motor)
```

will work